# IE window is going blank when using react portal to open a new window

Tags: javascript, reactjs, portal

Here is the code I am trying to use:
Please let me know if anything else needs to be done.
The code is working fine in chrome.
I am creating a splitview on the new window where in the left side would be the image and the right side would be another component.

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

export default class NewWindow extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            win: null, containerEl: null
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let win = window.open('', '', 'width=600,height=400');
        let containerEl = win.document.createElement('div');
        win.document.body.appendChild(containerEl);
        this.copyStyles(containerEl, win.document);
        this.setState({ win, containerEl });
    }

    copyStyles = (sourceDoc, targetDoc) => {
        Array.from(sourceDoc.styleSheets).forEach(styleSheet => {
            if (styleSheet.cssRules) {
                const newStyleEl = sourceDoc.createElement('style');

                Array.from(styleSheet.cssRules).forEach(cssRule => {
                    newStyleEl.appendChild(sourceDoc.createTextNode(cssRule.cssText));
                });

                targetDoc.head.appendChild(newStyleEl);
            } else if (styleSheet.href) {
                const newLinkEl = sourceDoc.createElement('link');

                newLinkEl.rel = 'stylesheet';
                newLinkEl.href = styleSheet.href;
                targetDoc.head.appendChild(newLinkEl);
            }
        });
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.state.win.close();
    }

    render() {
        const { containerEl } = this.state;
        if (!containerEl) {
            return null;
        }
        return ReactDOM.createPortal(this.props.children, containerEl);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you substituted something static, like say <div /> in place of this.props.children in the createPortal() call, does it have the same behaviour?

Comment: Thanks, but didn't work!!!

Comment: Getting Script5022 in IE Exception thrown and not caught